# OpenMP teams reduction behavior

Tags: c++, openmp, reduce

I am experimenting with OpenMP device support with the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

//---------------------------------------
#pragma omp declare target 
double testf (double x)
{
  return x * x + 2 * sin (x);
}
#pragma omp end declare target 

//---------------------------------------
double integrate (double st, double en, int div)
{
  double localRes = 0;
  double step = (en - st) / div;
 
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+: localRes)
  for (int i = 1; i < div; i++)
    {
      double x;
      x = st + i * step;
//       printf("Team %i Thread %i %lf\n", omp_get_team_num(), omp_get_thread_num(),x);
      localRes += testf (x);
    }
  localRes += (testf (st) + testf (en))/2;
  localRes *= step;
  return localRes;
}

//---------------------------------------
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  if (argc == 1)
    {
      cerr << "Usage " << argv[0] << " start end divisions\n";
      exit (1);
    }
  double start, end;
  int divisions;
  start = atof (argv[1]);
  end = atof (argv[2]);
  divisions = atoi (argv[3]);

  double finalRes = integrate (start, end, divisions);

  cout << finalRes << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile with clang, I see that only one team is used and I get the correct result. When I compile with g++, multiple teams are employed but I get the wrong answer.
Is this the expected behavior?
Compilation commands and results:

```
$ g++ -fopenmp -fno-stack-protector test.cpp -o test -foffload=-lm -fno-fast-math -fno-associative-math
$ ./test 0 1 100000
1.34147e-05
$ clang++-9 -fopenmp -fno-stack-protector test.cpp -o test
$ ./test 0 1 100000
1.25273
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you get the number of teams for each compilation setup, by calling `omp_get_num_teams`? The default number of teams `num_teams` is implementation defined.

Comment: If I modify the directive to: ```#pragma omp target teams num_teams(5) 
#pragma omp  distribute parallel for reduction(+: localRes)``` clang gives the same wrong result as gcc.  Also if I move the reduction clause to the teams line, a different - but still wrong- result is produced.

Comment: I cannot test it right now, but in some examples across various sites, I see that you don't need to use operator `+=` for `localRes`, as it is handled with the reduction spec. Can you test with the line `localRes = testf (x);`?

Comment: As for num_teams, it is great to see that you can have same behaviour with different compilers! :)